# What's the purpose of dissolving the ink in glass of water?

Tags: plot-explanation, mollys-game

Molly believes that there was one Yankee in particular that every man in
America would line up to lose to. In a motel room, she sits with a group of
young women whom she has hired to start a poker business:

> Molly: Don't say his name out loud. Write it on a cocktail napkin.
> Crumple the napkin up. **Put it in a glass of water, so they can see
> the ink dissolve**.
>
> Woman #1:That's really necessary?
>
> Molly: No, it's not at all necessary.

What's the purpose of dissolving the ink in glass of water ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What's the purpose of dissolving the ink in glass of water ?

This point is to ensure that no evidence of the name exists.

The ink will disperse in the water and thus the name erased making it seem that the name is important and must be kept secret.

Comment: It might be worth emphasising that this is theatre. The idea is to make it seem like it's a big enough secret that they can't even say it out loud.

Comment: Also, if said celeb doesn't turn up, they can't say "But you told me..." :-)